# Bar chart with coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm working with anonymization and the [GDA-Score](https://www.gda-score.org/). For a paper I wanted to make the following plots:

[image]

Can someone help me getting such a coordinate system with charts? So far I was only able to get a chart diagram in a box using tikz and pgfplots without a y-axis separating two areas. I also looked into the documentation, but that didn't help me. This is my first time creating charts (I only created function plots so far), and I hope I will learn something!

Comment: Any meaning for the numbers in your diagram?

Comment: It's important, that they are there, but they do not affect the size of the bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is drawing as it is. I hope the code is self-explained.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i/\j/\col/\lw/\itextB/\itextA in {
    1/2/cyan/7mm/0.94/Conf,
    2/2/cyan/7mm/1.00/Prob,
    3/2/gray/7mm/0.00/Know,
    4/1.5/gray/7mm/16.00/Work,
    5/2/gray/7mm/1.00/Susc,
    -.9/1.7/red/18mm/0.06/Combined
}{
\draw[color=\col,line width=\lw] (\i-.3,0)--+(90:-\j);
\path 
(\i-.3,0)   node[above=1mm,scale=.9]{\itextA}
(\i-.3,-\j) node[above,scale=.7]{\itextB};      
}
\draw[thick] (-3,0)--(5.5,0) 
(0,-2) node[below]{bad} -- (0,2) node[above]{good};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah I see, you simply skipped pgfplots and just did it in tikz. I thought it would be easier with pgfplots, but thats also very good. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Titanlord I see that `pgfplots` is powerful. However, it is too hard for me to remember a lot of option names, so I often use basic commands of plain TikZ.